# No success with createFileAtPath ("No such process")

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm having a problem saving some data to file.  The following line returns a NO:

```
[self.fileManager createFileAtPath:fileString contents:photoData attributes:nil];
```

The error code is 3 and the error message is "No such process."  The `fileString` variable points to a filename (e.g., "file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/... /Library/Caches/photos/2-86290") and `photoData` is an NSData variable (though a mouseover during debugging tells me it's actually an NSConcreteData variable).

Thanks for reading!  Any ideas on this would be terrific.

Comment: Also check out this answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578179/createfileatpath-ocunit-errno-blues/27805592#27805592

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `fileString` begins with `file://` then this isn't a path, it is a URL string for a file URL.

If you started with an `NSURL` object and obtained `fileString` as follows:

```
fileString = [someURL absoluteString];
```

then change it to:

```
fileString = [someURL path];
```

Now `fileString` will have a valid file path that you can pass to the `createFileAtPath:` method.

Another option, if you want to write the `NSData` object `photoData`, is to do:

```
[photoData writeToURL:someURL atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Hi maddy, thanks for the explanation.  Makes sense, and fixed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

An additional answer for people like me who came searching for this error and had no luck.

It seems that if your file name is too long you will also see the same error message. The limit appears to be around 250 characters.